# How can I read a row from a CSV file using a unique code?

Tags: python, csv

I have a system where a user can write details to a csv file and an ID is generated for that set of details. I'd like to be able to read a row of details from the file by inputting the ID corresponding to that row.

I've seen a query on here which is the same as mine, but I can't understand how it works and I think I would have to modify my code for it.

This is how the writing system works if it helps:

```
with open('students.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)

    forename = str(input("Enter student forename: "))
    surname = str(input("Enter student surname: "))
    birthdate = int(input("Enter student date of birth (format as daymonthyear): "))
    address = str(input("Enter student address: "))
    phone_number = int(input("Enter student home phone number: "))
    gender = str(input("Enter student gender: "))
    student_id = random.sample(range(1, 31), 30)

    writer.writerow([forename, surname, birthdate, address, phone_number, gender, student_id])
```

Comment: What guaranteeing that the `student_id` will be unique if this is done more than once (as seems likely)? Ignoring that issue, you would need to read each row of the csv file and see of `student_id` column contain whatever one was being sought - there's no shortcut.

Comment: It's set to never generate the same number twice.

Comment: Every time you call `random.sample()` like that, it will be as though it has never been called before — so a duplicate _is_ possible if that code is ever executed again.

Comment: I didn't think about that. How could I guarantee no duplicates?

Comment: @Mrmongoose64 because you're already editing in `a`ppend mode, you could just use the natural numbers as a natural (heh) identifier. I.e. start with `STUDENT_ID = 0` and every time you append to this file, increment `STUDENT_ID`. Or, use a [UUID](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/uuid.html) even though that's not an integer... There is a lot of options

Comment: Mrmongoose64: @ebb-earl-co ideas for generating unique ids sound good — I've included an example of implementing one of them in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is fairly easy with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
csvFile_df = pd.read_csv('students.csv', 
                         header=None, 
                         names=['forename', 'surname', 'birthdate', 'address', 'phone_number', 'gender', 'student_id'])

def return_row_of_details_from_file(df, col, val):
    """ Given pd.DataFrame, `df`, return row of `df` corresponding to
    column `col` having value `val`
    """
    return df[df[col]==val]

# bonus: a curried version of the above which is a ready-made `student_id`-searcher:
return_student_id_details = \
    lambda val, df=csvFile_df, col='student_id': df[df[col]==val]

# example:
details_for_student_7 = return_student_id_details(7)
```

This function is just dressed up `pandas` indexing, and will return the (sub)`DataFrame` consisting of the rows that match on the `val` inputted: for you, `student_id`. If the `student_id` values in `csvFile` are unique, then it will return a 1-row, 7-column `pd.DataFrame` if `student_id` passed to the function is in `df`, and and empty `pd.DataFrame` object if it's not.

The above really should have some error-handling like excepting `KeyError` for when `col` isn't in the `df`, and maybe some embellishments like returning the row(s) as a (list of) `dict`(s), etc., but it'll do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, it says that there's no module named pandas.

Comment: @Mrmongoose64: [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a popular open-source module that's not included with the Python distribution — so you'd need to install it in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, there's no shortcut to do what you want — so it's necessary to read the file and compare each row and see if it has the student id in it.

```
import csv

target_id = input("Enter target student id: ")
# For example: '03ebdf6c-4768-4838-8128-c75ee0a8306d'

with open('students.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvFile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvFile):
        if row[6] == target_id:
            print('Target id found:', row)
            break
    else:
        print('No student with id {} found'.format(target_id))
```

As I also mentioned, using `random.sample()` that way won't guarantee that the generated id's are unique. One simple way would be to use the built-in [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/uuid.html#module-uuid) module as shown below.

Student ids generated using it will be somewhat of long and ugly, but they all be unique. It might make more sense to just number them, that way they could be shorter, but the code for adding new ones would be (slightly) more complicated because it would require reading the entire file first in order to find the id of the last row currently in it.

Note how the csv file is opened with `newline-''` in both this and the previous snippet, which the way [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to do it and will avoid potential problems on some platforms.

```
import csv
from uuid import uuid4

with open('students.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)

    forename = input("Enter student forename: ")
    surname = input("Enter student surname: ")
    birthdate = input("Enter student date of birth (format as daymonthyear): ")
    address = input("Enter student address: ")
    phone_number = input("Enter student home phone number: ")
    gender = input("Enter student gender: ")

    student_id = uuid4()  # Generate unique random UUID.

    writer.writerow([forename, surname, birthdate, address, phone_number, gender,
                     student_id])
```